# Passing data from extension in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am building a complex interface in SwiftUI that I need to break into multiple extensions in order to be able to compile the code, but I can't figure out how to pass data between the extension and the body structure.

I made a simple code to explain it :

```
class Search: ObservableObject {
    @Published var angle: Int = 10
}

struct ContentView: View {
   @ObservedObject static var search = Search()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(ContentView.self.search.angle)")
            aTest()
        }
    }
}

extension ContentView {
    struct aTest: View {
        var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                Button(action: { ContentView.search.angle = 11}) { Text("Button")}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I press the button the text does not update, which is my issue. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: You don't need extension like that when separate views... also search & read about Binding.

Comment: Thanks @Asperi, I overlooked Binding and I will take a closer look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var search = Search()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(ContentView.self.search.angle)")
            aTest // call as a computed property
        }
    }
}

extension ContentView {
    var aTest: some View { // not a separate `struct` anymore
        ZStack {
            Button(action: { self.search.angle = 11 }) { Text("Button")}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! It does work like that, you just have to take out the "static" for the observedObject. Cheers